WebSocket Channels in Django not connecting
I'm struggling why still insist not being connected my WebSocket using Django, I've used laragon as Mysql and I just used my local database, and I just want to try first before saving to database it if it works or not but I getting an error. Did I forgot something?
Not Found: /ws/socket-server/

so I have this format
and I have error in my html url on line const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url)
html
$(document).ready(function () {
  let url = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket-server/`
  const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url)
  chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
      let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
      console.log('Data:', data)

      if(data.type === 'chat'){
          let messages = document.getElementById('messages')

          messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div> <p>${data.message}</p></div>`)
      }
  }
});

main/routing.py
from django.urls import re_path 
from main import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/socket-server/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
]

main/consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'test'

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()
   

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'chat_message',
                'message':message
            }
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'chat',
            'message':message
        }))

tev/asgi.py
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import main.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tev.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http':get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            main.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ....
   'channels',
]
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'tev.asgi.application'


Put Daphne at the top of the list for a try.

@Chukwujiobi Canon what do you mean and what should I put?

what is the full url of your websocket like are you using daphne or uvicorn? This is how i use asgi server to work with websockets, here beauty_palace is my server name.
uvicorn beauty_palace.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7002

@Tanveer I just used channels but I don't know how can I work the url, but the default I just use url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

no, this will not work, please see this documentation https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
